# How to Print Two Columns in File Output

Tags: python

How would I print my output in two columns where they are lined up side by side. I have it set up so that it prints two columns but my data is not lined up. Oh and by the way I'm not allowed to use use lists, tuples, sets or dictionaries. In particular you cannot use the string split() method because it returns a list.

```
my_file=open("project05.data.txt", "r")
outfile = open("dummy.txt","w")
header = my_file.readline()
print("{:^80}".format(header[67:72]),file=outfile)

state = my_file.readline()
print(state[0:17],file=outfile)

count=0

for line in my_file:
    count+=1
    print(line[0:17],file=outfile) 

    data="{:^80}".format(line[67:75].rstrip())
    print(data,file=outfile)
    if count > 10:
        break
outfile.close()

Output:
                                 1+MMR                                      
U.S. National    
Alabama          
                                89.7+5.8                                    
Alaska           
                                90.5+3.6                                    
Arizona          
                                91.4+3.7                                    
Arkansas         
                                88.3+5.9                                    
California       
                                90.7+5.3                                    
Colorado         
                                86.0+5.5                                    
Connecticut      
                                91.4+5.4                                    
Delaware         
                                94.8+3.4                                    
Dist. of Columbia
                                96.2+3.1                                    
Florida          
                                93.4+4.0                                    
Georgia          
                                93.9+4.1
```

Comment: How is it not lined up? You're printing two columns, one that is always 16 characters wide, and one that is always 8 wide but right-justified in an 80-character field.  So in a way it is lined up.  Post a sample of the output you expect to get, and the output that you're getting instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, the fact that you're writing the output to a file makes no difference.

Comment: Example of input files and expected output?

Comment: Output Posted... As you can see its it two columns but the data is not exactly side by side

Comment: @Iguananaut ah wait, now I get it. The OP is printing two lines. The *columns* are aligned, but the rows are not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the restrictions make this *blatantly* a "do my homework" question.

Comment: It obviously isn't. I did the work for myself I just needed help with lining some things up. Aren't you a stickler -_- @LegoStormtroopr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `print` twice. `print` always outputs onto a new line. If you want both columns on the same line, you simply have to combine your two format specifiers into a single string:

```
for line in my_file:
    count += 1
    output = "{}{:^80}".format(line[0:17], line[67:75].rstrip())
    print(output, file=outfile)
    if count > 10:
        break
```

Of course, you should also wrap your files in the appropriate [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) statement:

```
with open('infile') as my_file, open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    #above code goes here
# Now don't need to close explisitly
```

Comment: On Python 3 you can also use the `print(output, file=outfile, end='')`.  That way you can use multiple print statements to write to the same line.

Comment: Indeed, though at that point you might as well use `my_file.write()` instead ;)

Comment: Agreed--I was thinking maybe the OP hadn't learned that yet :)